# Default Initialization of Private Fields in Java

Tags: java

Say I have a class called Person:

```
class Person{
    private int num = 1;
}
```

When calling the empty constructor for class Person, will Java first initialize num to a default value of zero, and then assign num to 1? Or will Java initialize num to 1 straight away? Doesn't C++ do the former unless you use initializer syntax?

Thank You!

Comment: How would you tell the difference?

Comment: I'm not sure. I figure it would be best to initialize fields to the value you specified and not spend time initializing them to a default value.

Comment: initializing all the class variables to their default value is really easy: just set a contiguous block of memory to all zeros. This strategy is fast and easy to implement - a lot easier than trying to work out what isn't initialized (say, if variables are set conditionally), and so is obviously less vulnerable to problems with using uninitialized memory, making it secure. Don't try to second guess the performance, but also don't discount benefits beyond performance.

Answer (score 13):

It would assign the value zero first.

If you put something before the field declaration like so, you could see this:

```
class Person{
    { print(); }
    private int num = 1;
    { print(); }

    void print() {
      System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

This would print:

```
0
1
```

This is described in [JLS Sec 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a *default value* when it is created

And [Sec 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4) (emphasis added and some parts omitted):

> The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in the specified class type and all its superclasses. **As each new field instance is created, it is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5)**.
>
> ...
>
> Next, **the selected constructor of the specified class type is invoked** ...

In other words, object creation and constructor invocation are distinct operations, and the fields are initialized to their default values prior to the invocation of the constructor.

The actual field initialization occurs in the constructor: field initializes are inlined into every constructor that invokes `super(...)`, immediately after the call to `super(...)`. The following is exactly equivalent to the above:

```
 class Person{
   private int num;

   Person() {
     super();
     print();
     num = 1;
     print();
   }

   void print() {
     System.out.println(num);
   }
}
```

One subtle point to make it that although declaring the field `final` would make the output of this code:

```
1
1
```

This does not mean that final variables are initialized sooner. All that has changed in that case is that `num` has become a compile-time constant expression, and thus is inlined. As such, `print()` would actually be executing:

```
System.out.println(1);
```

In other words, it does not read the field at all.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

*Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler.*

Considering this enunciation, I would say that Java will assign the value straight away.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean false
byte    (byte) 0
short   (short) 0
int 0
long    0L
char    \u0000
float   0.0f
double  0.0d
object reference    null
```

Here are all the default values of Java. It will be init by this by default any variable with this. So with answer of Andy I can conclude that it will be always first 0 then it will go by the value you give to the variable.